# Hive query to transform an array of struct to array of string

Tags: sql, arrays, struct, hive, hiveql

My use case is as following:

I want to copy data from Table-A to Table-B and **transform field1** from array of struct to array of string where the string is the val1 property of struct in table-A and ignore val2.

```
Table-A:
field1: array<struct<val1: str, val2: int>>
sample data:
[{val1: "abc", val2: 123}, {val1: "def", val2: 456}], [{val1: "xyz", val2: 789}]

Table-B:
field1: array<string>
sample data:
["abc", "def"], ["xyz"]
```

I am not able to figure out how I can select the field1 column with transformation on it through hive query language.

The things I was able to figure out was I could explode the array, perform a select of the val1 and then do collect_list but after trying multiple times could not get the correct syntax.

My query was like:

```
select collect_list(select col.val1 
  from explode(field1) as col) from table-A
```

I also want to strictly do it through hiveql and not through a udf in python.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post some sample data with the expected output and your attempt?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala, added the sample data. my query was like: select collect_list(select col.val1 from explode(field1) as col) from table-A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode original array using [Lateral View + explode](http://%20https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) and collect array of struct.val1 using collect_set() or collect_list():

```
with mydata as (--This is your data example, use your table instead of this CTE
select stack (2,
array(named_struct("val1", "abc", "val2", 123), named_struct("val1", "def", "val2", 456)), 
array(named_struct("val1", "xyz", "val2", 789))
) as myarray
)

select t.myarray as original_array, collect_set(s.val1) as result_array
  from mydata t
       lateral view explode(myarray) e as s --struct
group by t.myarray
```

Result:

```
original_array                                          result_array
[{"val1":"abc","val2":123},{"val1":"def","val2":456}]   ["abc","def"]
[{"val1":"xyz","val2":789}]                             ["xyz"]
```

Your structure can be also declared as map, not struct. In this case use `s['val1']` instead of `s.val1` to get map element.

Answer (score 0):

There is some magic in the handling of arrays that allow you to do this:

```
select t.myarray as original_array, t.myarray.val1 from mydata t
```

I.e. selecting struct field `val1` from an array of structs will return an array of `val1`

From http://thornydev.blogspot.com/2013/07/querying-json-records-via-hive.html